# how can i use RemoveChild Node correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, removechild

i want to remove one of the element which inside my table,

i try to use tr.removeChild(tr.childNodes[2]);

to remove my third row elements, but it doesn't really work

```
function smile()
{
document.getElementById("p1").style.backgroundImage = 'url(smile.jpg)';
}
function twice()
{
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML="Smile Smile";
}
function empty()
    {
//this is the part i want to remove , i want to remove the text inside it
    tr.removeChild(tr.childNodes[3]);
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<table border = "1" >
<form>
<tr>
<th onclick="smile()"><input type="button" name="person1" value="Make it smile!" id="person4" size="30" </th>
<th onclick="twice()"><input type="button" name="person1" value="Make it smile twice!" id="person4" size="30" </th>
<th onclick="empty()"><input type="button" name="person1" value="Make it empty" id="person4" size="30" </th>
</tr>
```

Comment: Note that duplicate (and triplicate) ids are invalid, they must be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SbDXC/

I see a couple issues with your code.

First, you need to define tr (see the demo).

Second, in a table, using rows and cells is more reliable than childNodes. To remove the third cell (index 2) of the first row (index 0), simply use:

```
table.rows[0].removeChild(table.rows[0].cells[2]);​
```

The issue with childNodes is that in some browsers the line breaks will be counted as nodes.

[Edit] Even shorter: `table.rows[0].deleteCell(2);​`

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

- You need to set `tr` inside of the `empty()` function, right now it isn't set to anything.
- Arrays are indexed starting at 0, so you are telling it to remove the 4th child. Try changing it to:

  tr.removeChild(tr.childNodes[2]);

Comment: it doesn"t work , and i juz mischange it when i post the code , i had try tr.removeChild(tr.childNodes[2]);

Comment: See my update, you need to set the `tr` variable in your `empty` method